# What does 'public performances required of a barrister' mean?

Tags: barristers

> [ [Source :](http://www.theguardian.com/news/2016/apr/14/the-lawyer-who-takes-the-cases-no-one-wants?CMP=share_btn_tw) ] He [UK Solicitor Tom Giles] thought about becoming a teacher before taking a conversion course and going into legal aid. “It’s a cliche, isn’t it – growing up in a lesbian household in the 80s, in Stoke Newington – what are you going to do? Join Ukip and end up an estate agent?” As a shy child who nevertheless “would not give a point up”, he could not imagine undertaking **[1.] the public performances required of a barrister**, and so trained as a solicitor. He came to Oxford because his wife had got a job at the council, and he admits he “stalked” Philip Turpin, one of the firm’s partners, until he was hired.

I do not understand the meaning of 1, which appears to subdue a more direct, open reason.
Does 1 refer to the more public acts of advocacy and public speaking and verbal argument?

Answer (score 1):

A barrister is a performance profession like educator, politician or actor. It is their job to perform for the judge and the jury and convince them to find for their client.

This is not to say the law is not important but, things that are open and shut settle before anyone gets anywhere near a courtroom (or the accused makes a plea deal); therefore barristers are arguing things that are ... arguable. The barrister who argues the law best wins.